# Find which argument is false in "if" in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

There are supposed to be three files in my directory. I need to know which of them is missing at different times
I'm trying a bash script using "if" (putting in crontab)

```
if [ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -f file3 ] ; then
echo "All three exist" >> logfile
else
echo "<*NAME OF FILE THAT IS NOT PRESENT*> is not present" >> logfile
fi
```

I know it is possible to get it using nested "if" separately for all files. But i don't want to use separate "if"s for each file.
I also know it is possible to use a for loop. But I want to know if the above is feasible - to keep the script to a minimum size.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm. This is cheating, but you can do `test -f file1 | test -f file2 | test -f file3` and you'll get a result similar to and-ing the tests, but you can look at PIPESTATUS to see what actually failed. Please don't actually do this – it creates n subshells and doesn't boolean shortcut, but hey.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not possible to determine which condition in an `&&` chain failed.

But, using a `for` loop isn't so bad:

```
success=true
for f in file1 file2 file3; do
    if ! [ -f $f ]; then
        success=false
        echo "$f is not present" >> logfile
    fi
done
if $success; then
    echo "All three exist" >> logfile
fi
```

It also lets you determine if multiple files don't exist, in the event that that information is valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to do the test for you, then use side-effects of the function to detect boolean shortcuts:

```
##
# Test that a file exists. Here we use standard output to just visibly see
# that the function is running, but for a more programmatic solution, 
# store state: You could use a shared variable to store the names of files
# that you know exist, or you could just keep a counter of the number of times
# this function is run. Use your imagination.
file_exists() {
  printf 'Testing that %s exists\n' "$1"
  test -f "$1"
}

if file_exists file1 && file_exists file2 && file_exists file3; then
    …
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of something with this:

```
for i in {1..3} 
  do  
    ...do some things...file$i 
    ...do more things...
  done
```

But that would add a further layer of abstraction not really needed for only three files.